# Can a Facebook Page App post to a user wall without the user's explicit permission?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook app for a companies facebook pages. Ie the app is used as a special tab on the facebook pages.

Can I get it to post to the current user's wall without having to ask the user to install and authorise the app in the way you would for a fully fledged app like farmville?

FYI - I'm currently using the latest PHP sdk

Answer (score 3):

> Can I get it to post to the current user's wall without having to ask the user to install and authorise the app in the way you would for a fully fledged app like farmville?

No, users must always explicitly give an application permission to post content. It'd be hugely abused - any tab you visited might spam your wall to hell.

Answer (score 0):

Your app cannot post info on the user's wall unless explicitly given permission by the user. The user has control over all aspects of their account and having non-consensual access results could result in wall spamming.

Therefore if your app wishes to post to their wall, explicit permission is required.

Comment: He was giving FarmVille as an example of apps that make you authorize before they post for you.